# Add layout for ImageView

Tags: java, android, image

I have an ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/auto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:src="@drawable/auto" />
```

How can I add layout for this image in onCreate for Activity? For instance, I want add background for this image. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose it in a Layout and add a background to the Layout.